# Encrypting text with cesar cipher, str.replace gives TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, attributeerror, caesar-cipher

`cipher.py`:

```
import argparse

def parse_command_line():  
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("infile",type=str,help="input file to be encrypted or decrypted")

    parser.add_argument("-o outfile_path","--outfile outfile_path",type=str,help="output file")
    parser.add_argument("-k KEY","--key KEY",type=int,default=1,help="encryption/decryption key (must be positive) (default= 1)")
    parser.add_argument("-d","--decrypt",action="store_true",help="decrypt the input file")
    parser.add_argument("-a","--all",action="store_false",help="decrypt using all keys [1, 25], save outputs in different files. (useful in case the key is lost orunknown)")
    parser.add_argument("-v","--verbose",action="store_true",help="Verbose mode")

    args=parser.parse_args()
    return args 
    pass



def transform(message, key, decrypt):

    #TODO: Your code goes here
    if decrypt:
        for i in message:
            temp=shift(i,key)
            transformed_message=message.replace(i,temp,1)
            message=transformed_message
    return transformed_message
    pass
def shift(char, key):     
    # ordered lower case alphabet
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    # will contain shifted lower case alphabet
    shifted_alphabet = ''
    for i in range(len(alphabet)):
        shifted_alphabet = shifted_alphabet + alphabet[(i + key) % 26]

    if char.isalpha():
        char_index = alphabet.index(char.lower())
        shifted_char = shifted_alphabet[char_index]

        # keep char's case (upper or lower)
        if char.isupper():
            return shifted_char.upper()
        else:
            return shifted_char

def main():
    # parse command line arguments
    args = parse_command_line()

    # key is specified
    if not args.all:
        # encrypt/decrypt content of infile
        outstring = transform(instring, args.key, args.decrypt)

        # write content of outstring to outfile
        write_file(outstring, args.outfile)

    # key is not specified, try all keys from 1 to 25 to decrypt infile
    else:
        for k in range(1, 26):
            # decrypt content of infile
            outstring = transform(instring, k, True)

            # write content of outstring to outfile
            write_file(outstring, "decrypted_by_" + str(k) + ".txt")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm running this with:

```
$ python3 cipher.py plain_message.txt -k 23 -v -o cipher_message.txt
```

and the file is:

```
Software is a great combination between artistry and engineering.

--Bill Gates
```

but this gives the following traceback instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cipher.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "cipher.py", line 218, in main
    outstring = transform(instring, k, True)
  File "cipher.py", line 141, in transform
    transformed_message=message.replace(i,temp,1)
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

I tried to run `transform(message,key, decrypt)` separately, it returns strings with no problem.

Please only check `parse_command_line()` and `transform(message,key, decrypt)`,
as `shift()` and `main()` are pre-written, and these should work with no problems.

Comment: We also don't need *everything*, we need just a small example that reproduces the problem, please narrow down the post to one. I see now that you do have a traceback here, but it is lost in one big code block. Perhaps you could split those up?

Comment: Right, now that we have this in a slightly better shape: you need to stick to one problem at a time. Please remove one of the two problems and keep that for another question.

Comment: Thanks for the instruction ,can you now release it?

Comment: Might want to avoid calling replace function in transform() when temp is None. It looks like this just means the character was non-alphanumeric (a space, a number, or punctuation.) I'm not sure what that "Namespace object" error is about, though.

Comment: @NathanMills: the object returned by `argparse.ArgumentParser().parse_args()` is a `Namespace` object. So the `parse_args` result has no `key` entry.

Comment: I'm still not sure we can actually help here, because we don't know what `shift()` returns. If it is pre-written, take a look at that code and see if it could end up *not returning anything* or explicitly returning `None`. You can't pass `None` to `str.replace()`.

Comment: it returns shifted_char, I put the shift() part back there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error stems from your `shift()` function when encountering the last character of your files first line of text: 
`'Software is a great combination between artistry and engineering.'`

The `.`is not `isalpha()` so the shift() function does not explicitly return anything which means it implicitly returns `None`.

Your transform method does not handle `None` gracefully:

```
def transform(message, key, decrypt):
    if decrypt:
        for i in message:
            temp=shift(i,key)
            transformed_message=message.replace(i,temp,1) # does not work if temp == None
            message=transformed_message
    return transformed_message
    pass
```

You can avoid the error by not replacing if `temp is None`:

```
def transform(message, key, decrypt): 
    if decrypt:
        for i in message:
            temp=shift(i,key)
            if temp: # check if not Falsy - None is falsy, "if temp is not None:" works too
                transformed_message=message.replace(i,temp,1)

             # assigning something to message does nothing, so removed it
    return transformed_message
```

If you are allowed to change the shift() function itself, I would probably just return the (unchanged) non-mapped character which would work as well.